# Timezone information of remote file , daylight saving

Tags: curl, timezone, libcurl, dst

How do you get the time zone information for a remote file using libcurl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files don't have time zones. What exactly are you trying to determine? The time zone in which a user created a file? The time zone in which the server hosting the file resides? The time zone in which the client downloading the file resides? HTTP/1.1 (and I'm assuming you're only interested in HTTP) doesn't provide any representation of time that includes a time zone. There are various web services that will guess at the physical location of a server based on an IP address, and some that will even return a time zone based on that guess, but it's hard to know if that's the kind of thing you're looking for.

Comment: suppose i have a FILETIME which has some value (which we can see by converting it to systemtime) .. when i am in timezone1 . suppose i changed my timezone to timezone2 ..now i want to get the time in hours and minutes(format) which was in timezone1.

Comment: curl will set the downloaded file's time correctly when using the -R option. Whichever utility you use to view that time should automatically convert to the local time zone when it's displayed, e.g. doing it programatically using stat()+localtime()+strftime(). To force a particular time zone, see tzset().